# Set virtual directory as root in apache

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache

In my linux server my www root of apache server is /var/www/html, I have a folder called blog in the above mentioned path. I have to access the the website in the blog folder by specifying `http://myDomain/blog/`. My question is I want to be able to access the website by specifying `http://myDomain` in the browser(without having to move the contents of the blog folder to www root). Is there any parameter which I can set in the config file so as to be able to achieve the mentioned objective.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file and search for DocumentRoot and change from

```
/var/www/html
```

TO

```
/var/www/html/blog
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Apache httpd.conf file, just set the DocumentRoot as being /var/www/html/blog.